# What is an appropriate variance correction to apply here?

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity

I' am giving a toy example here for clarity, but I wish to apply this to a real problem I've encountered.

Say for every block in a city I measure the population and the average building height. Now, I notice that with increasing average building height the variance in population also increases. See below for simulation data:

[image]

```
n <- 10000
building_height <- rpois(n,10)
population <- rnorm(n,mean=100,sd=building_height)
png("population-buildingHeight.png")
plot(building_height,population,xlab="Average building height",ylab="Population")
dev.off()
```

Where,
$$ population \sim N(\mu=100, \sigma=buildingHeight) $$
$$ buildingHeight \sim Poisson(\lambda=10) $$

Say that I don't expect variance in population to depend on average building height, and for the purposes of downstream statistical anaylses, I want to correct the bias. So I come up with an ad hoc method to correct the bias:

[image]

```
variances <- c()
for (i in min(building_height):max(building_height)) {
  tmp <- population[building_height==i]
  if (length(tmp)>1) {
    variances <- c(variances,sd(population[building_height==i]))
  } else {
    variances <- c(variances,NA)
  }
}

median_variance = median(variances,na.rm=T)
median_population = median(population)
population <- population - median_population
population.corrected <- population
nn <- 1
for (i in min(building_height):max(building_height)) {
  sub_population <- population[building_height==i]
  if (length(sub_population)>1) {
    correction <- median_variance/variances[nn]
    sub_population <- sub_population * correction
    population.corrected[building_height==i] <- sub_population
  }
  nn <- nn + 1
}

population.corrected <- population.corrected + median_population

png("population-buildingHeight-corrected.png")
plot(building_height,population.corrected,xlab="Average building height",ylab="Population",ylim=c(50,160))
dev.off()
```

The math:

Let $p_i$ and $h_i$ be the population and average building height for the $i^{th}$ city block. Let $ph_j=\{p_i | h_i = j\}$ be the set of population values that are from city blocks that have average building height $j$. Then let
$sd_j$ be the standard deviation of $ph_j$. Compute $ph_{median}$, which is the median of all the $sd_j$ values, and $p_{median}$ which is the median of all $p_i$ values. Finally, perform the correction:

$$
pcorrected_i = \frac{ph_{median}}{sd_j}(p_i-p_{median})+p_{median}, where \hspace{0.1cm} p_i \in ph_j
$$

But I wonder if there might be a better method?

Comment: Could you simplify the program codes into math equations?

Comment: @a_statistician I added some math equations to the main post.

Comment: What do you want to do? (the objective of the study). Basically, I think this data transformation is unacceptable.

Comment: Maybe my ad hoc solution is unacceptable, but surely there are some published methods out there? Correcting for heterosketasticity is common in statistics, and I think my issue does not seem too different. The real problem I' am trying to apply this to is in cancer genomics--and I observe bias in my data similar to the above example, which is hampering the analysis I' am trying to do. And similar bias corrections are performed for the type of data I' am working with. I go into further detail if you want, but I think the toy example I provided here captures the relevant parts of the problem.

Comment: After correction for heterosketasticity, what will you do on corrected variable? Or if the original data has no heterosketasticity, what will you do?

Comment: I will apply an [algorithm](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004873) to produce a figure like the one at the top of [this](https://cnvkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plots.html) page. If the data in that figure were biased like mine, then the black/grey dots would have much higher variance, and hence, deconvoluting the data to get those red dots is much harder. If there is not heterosketasticity then I will not need to apply the bias correction.

Comment: I still did not get your objective of the study.